# Which rules do I need to apply in Security Group for private instance in AWS to allow Informatica links to work outsitr the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, informatica

I have "informatica" running inside **my private instance** **which I'm able to connect with VPN**.  Informatica links are working inside my instance.
Which rule should I allow so that I can access the URL from my personal PC, Though I'm connected to VPN, I'm not able to access them.

I didn't assigned any DNS.
I'm trying to access with

<\Private-IP>:1512/pim/webaccess

<\Private-IP>:9090/hsx/html/login.html

These URL's are working on my EC2 instance. But when I try to access outside my instance, I'm getting "This site can't be reached" for both URL's.

[image]

Current Security Group rules are:

1. RDP : Security Group of VPN

I tried by adding "HTTP/HTTPS" rule to Security Group, but no change.

Comment: What are the URLs that you are trying to use? Are they to a specific IP address, or are they do a DNS Name? If it's a DNS Name, what IP address do they resolve to if you try to Ping that DNS Name? Exactly what happens when you try to access them -- does it return an error message? Does it fail immediately, or does it take a while to fail? What are the current settings of the Security Group on the instance? Please add all this information to your Question rather than answering in a comment.

Comment: I added the required information @JohnRotenstein. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Are you sure your VPN works using browser? Maybe traffic still tries to go over the internet, not your VPN?

Comment: @Marcin, I connected to VPN. Able to do RDP to my instance. If I add "All ICMP - IP4" to my security group, I'm even able to "ping" my instance to it's private IP from my PC. How to make traffic go over VPN?. I used OVPN and used AWS VPN certificate for connection.

Comment: @Pop When you say that you added HTTP/S rules to the Security Group, to what IP range did you open it? And was it in the Inbound Rules or Outbound Rules?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I opened HTTP/S inbound to VPN Security Group. Am I wrong?

Comment: What about using `curl <\Private-IP>:1512/pim/webaccess`? Not a regular browser.

Comment: @Marcin, I'm getting curl: (7) Failed to connect to <\IP> port 1512: Timed out

Comment: Can you create second instance in same subnet/vpc as the main one. Then curl your website from it. This will allow you to check if the issue is the instance itself, or your vpn.

Comment: Marcin, when you meant "Curl", do I need to check from my EC2, or from my PC. Again, the URL is working on EC2, but not on my PC. Even though I'm connected to VPN.

Comment: @Marcin, I tried CURL from another instance frrom same VPC,Subnet and also SG. But got same error.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, any suggestions?.

Comment: Just because two EC2 instances are "in the same security group" doesn't mean that they can communicate with each other. Security Groups are _applied to each instance individually_, so if there is no rule that permits inbound access from 'itself', connections will be refused. I recommend that on the Informatica instance, open the Inbound security group for ports 1512 and 9090 to the entire VPC range. Then attempt to connect between the EC2 instances again. If that fails, then open All Traffic to the VPC and try again. This will help you discover whether the Security Groups are the problem.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein My requirement is Only 1 EC2, on which informatica URL's are working. But those are not working on my personal PC. Can I acheive that with  ports 1512 and 9090 to the entire VPC range.?.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I tried by adding All Traffic,1512 and 9090 to my entire VPC. No responce from the URL's from my Personal PC..

Comment: It's best if you can test it from another Amazon EC2 instance first, since that removes the VPN from being a potential problem. The basic testing steps are: 1: Test that it is reachable from the same instance. 2: Test that it is reachable from a different EC2 instance. 3: Test that it is reachable via the VPN. Depending where it fails will give you a hint as to where to find the problem.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I tried accessing URL's from another instance, allowed All Traffic, 1512, 9090 and HTTP from VPC range, VPN. Still unable to access the page from another instance. Did I missed any inbound rules?.

Comment: Has anybody changed the NACLs from their default "Allow All" rules? Failing that, it sounds like a problem related to Informatica on the instance itself. Perhaps it isn't binding to external ports (not that I understand such stuff).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I didn't changed anything with NACL. Is there any alternative, other than Informatica ports?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It seems like we need to allow PORTS (1512, 9090 - which I was using for my links) "inbound" rules inside my EC2 instance. Even though I allowed those rules on my Security Group, it is not allowed in my EC2 instance.